Company plans to build a power plant in the Middle East with smoke stacks described as "fire-breathing dragons"
Many years ago when I first came to the U.S. and barely understood or spoke English I saw a movie I would like to see again but have never been able to find it. It was about building a power plant with I believe 3 or 7 smoke stacks somewhere in the Middle East and a prophecy about the stacks being called fire breathing dragons and the end of the world. I remember the planning company was doing a study and the board members were to meet a year later to make the final decision. 
During that year a board member somehow ended up in the Middle East amongst it's people, learned about the prophecy, took on a wife, had a child, lived poorly amongst the people. On the day of the board meeting, he went back and made sure the plant was not built. 
I keep trying to find this movie and still can't find it. Does anyone remember this movie? I would like to see it again. It's from the 70's or 80's.

Welcome to Movies & TV! I've edited your question title to make it more useful. If you feel I have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question. Stringing together a bunch of keywords doesn't really make a helpful title.

Sounds a lot like Holocaust 2000 with Kirk Douglas.

Despite doomsday warnings from throngs of locals, wealthy industrialist Robert Caine (Kirk Douglas) makes the controversial decision to build a nuclear power plant near a sacred cave in the Middle East. But before Caine can reap the benefits of his latest bid for global domination, he discovers that his son, Angel (Simon Ward), is the Antichrist, who is planning to use his father's project to trigger the end of the world.

He winds up protesting the plant and imagines it as a 7-headed dragon. Here's the trailer (in Arabic):




Oh, and Franz came to the same conclusion! (I was actually about to delete mine)

You were 30 seconds faster ;-)

Ah, sorry about that. ;)

Looks like it but something about it is different.  is this a remake?  I remember the quality of the movie being poor and the stacks being regular stacks not those round things.  I'll watch this one tonight.

[remake] Not that I know of. If anything, it's a bit of an Omen rip-off
